# phpmailer subject from variable creates encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send emails using php.

When i try to send special (Turkish) character within the subject, it displays html entity in the sent email. If I include the same variable in the body part, it works fine. Please see below:

```
$mail->Subject = $stuname."PhD Qualifying Exam Application";
```

I have tried html_entity_decode function but didnt work.

Also, if I type the Turkish character instead of getting from a variable, it works fine.

Finally, if I print the variable before sending the email, it prints fine without any encoding problem. But number of character is larger than it should be..

So, any idea why I am having encoding problem in subject are when getting the value from a variable?

Thank you!

PS:

i am also adding these headers:

```
$mail->SetLanguage("tr", "phpmailer/language");
$mail->CharSet  ="utf-8";
$mail->Encoding="base64";
```

Comment: Setting the language does nothing to sent messages - it just changes the language used for error messages. You don't need to set `Encoding`. All you need is `CharSet = 'UTF-8'`. If you're still getting corruption, it's coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, none of the html decoding functions were working so I wrote my own function for Turkish characters.

```
function replacehtml($inputText) {
    $replace  = array('İ','ı','Ö','ö','Ü','ü','Ç','ç','Ğ','ğ','Ş','ş');
    $search = array('&#304;','&#305;','&#214;','&#246;','&#220;','&#252;','&#199;','&#231;','&#286;','&#287;','&#350;','&#351;');
    $outputText=str_replace($search, $replace, $inputText);
    return $outputText;
}
```